# how to connect java code with c# code?

Tags: c#, java

I have C# code which will capture the msg from the mobile phone and respond to it. I need to connect this code with jpcap in java in order to capture the packets according to the request from the mobile phone. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

What about using a webservices, also may be [wcf rest service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd315413.aspx) something good in this case.

Comment: quote Amr,wcf is the best way for me